# d3 Undefined Error When Using R2D3 in IE8

Tags: jquery, svg, d3.js, internet-explorer-8

I am attempting to use R2D3 to support SVG elements in IE8.  I know, tell people not to use IE8 but in this case it's out of my control (i.e., corporate).  So, I've included d3 as follows in my Head:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<?php include("getUsers.php");?>
<!--[if lt IE 7]>
<html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>
<html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>
<html class="no-js lt-ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!-->
<html class="no-js"> <!--<![endif]-->
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<title>DRED</title>
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<script src="js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
<!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->

<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="js/html5shiv.js"></script>
<script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->

<script src="js/vendor/modernizr-2.6.2.min.js"></script>

<script src="sizzle/src/sizzle.js"></script>

<script src="js/plugins.js"></script>
<script src="js/main.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!-- Bootstrap -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery-ui.css"/>
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!--[if lte IE 8]>
<script src="r2d3/inst/_js/r2d3.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<![endif]-->

<!--[if gte IE 9]>
<script charset="utf-8" src="r2d3/inst/_js/d3.v2.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->

<script src="js/script.js"></script>
```

This is with the version of d3 provided with R2D3 but I have also tried with the regular d3 version with no change in results.

As soon as my javascript (js/script.js) hits the following line it throws an error in IE8: 'd3' is undefined

```
div = d3.select("body").append("div")
    .attr("class","tooltip")
    .style("opacity",0);
```

Any advice would be very much appreciated.

Comment: What's with your conditional comments? Missing opening `<`, unnecessary `<!-->` and `<!--`.

Comment: My understanding is that this is the correct format for IE If statements in the <head> section

Comment: Sorry, hit return too fast.  Here is a reference:  http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html

Comment: Sorry, I just noticed when I copied and pasted here that I left out the first "<" in the example  It was not like that in my code and is corrected now.

Comment: Your conditional comments look nothing like the ones in the link you provided. I'm talking especially about the gte IE 9 part: the first and the last line of it.

Comment: Also, do you include those scripts before or after your `d3.select`? The script might be in a different directory as well.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback Oleg, I have corrected the IE 9 portion but, unfortunately, it didn't fix the problem.  I have put my entire head section above, should have done that earlier.